# "Infective" or "Infectious"

Tags: differences, word-usage

I checked the dictionary only to find these two words clubbed into a single entry. Have these words evolved into one, having started differently?

> His enthusiasm was infectious.

Does "infective" fit there? Personally my answer is a no. On the other hand, when talking about diseases, both the words seem to fit. Is there any rule or pattern to the usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in saying that the word *infective* does not fit in the sentence "His enthusiasm was infectious."

NOAD says: "[...] *infectious* usually refers to the spread of positive things, such as good humor or optimism."

In this light, we should use the 'rule' exemplified by NOAD, as you said. So, in figurative sense we should say "His enthusiasm was *infectious*", not "His enthusiasm was *infective*." (See the NGRAM below.)

In order to answer your second question, first of all we should note that it is not true that "when talking about diseases, both the words seem to fit." In fact, as we can read in **Merriam-Webster's Medical Dictionary**, "infectious disease" is defined:

> a disease caused by the entrance into the body of organisms which grow
>   and multiply there;

while *infective* is defined:

> producing or capable of producing infection.

In this light, it seems that *infectious* is referred to the process, while *infective* is referred to the agent.

However, for instance, we can **usually** speak of "infectious hepatitis", but not of "infective hepatitis" as OAD defines this usage "SPECIAL USAGE - DATED".

---

[The following NGRAM](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enthusiasm+was+infectious%2Centhusiasm+was+infective%2Centhusiasm+was+contagious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=30) describes 'enthusiasm was infectious', 'enthusiasm was infective', 'enthusiasm was contagious'.

[image]

Also, "enthusiasm was infectious" ("enthusiasm was contagious") gets 38,900 (50,200) hits on Google Books, while "enthusiasm was infective" gets 5 hits.

In the Ngram I also reported "enthusiasm was contagious" because in non-technical texts there is little or no distinction between *infectious* and *contagious*.

Comment: "NOAD says: '[...] infectious usually refers to the spread of positive things, such as good humor or optimism.'" However, it is contrasting the metaphorical sense of *infectious* with that of *contagious*, so I don't think that part applies.

Comment: The NOAD supports the idea that *infectious* refers to the spread of an infection, while *infective* refers to its cause.

Comment: @zpletan NOAD - contagious and infectious: Strictly, a contagious disease is one transmitted by physical contact, whereas an infectious one is transmitted via microorganisms in the air or water. In practice, there is little or no difference in meaning between contagious and infectious when applied to disease or its spread. In figurative senses, contagious may describe the spread of good things such as laughter and enthusiasm or bad ones such as violence or panic, whereas infectious usually refers to the spread of positive things, such as good humor or optimism

Comment: Right—I too saw the usage note at *contagious*. What I'm saying is that you make it sound as though this note is contrasting *infectious* with *infective*, when it makes no statement, even an implied one, about *infective*. (To be clear, I don't disagree with your end result—*infective* has no postive metaphorical meaning. I'm simply questioning the pertinence of your source.)

Answer (score 2):

*Infectious* is one of the meanings of *infective*, but in my experience *infectious* is the more common word.

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports that *infectious* means:

- [of a disease, or disease-causing organism] likely to be transmitted to people, organisms, etc., through the environment.
- likely to spread infection: "The dogs may still be infectious."
- likely to spread or influence others in a rapid manner: "Her enthusiasm is infectious."

*Infective* means:

- capable of causing infection.
- [dated] infectious: *infective hepatitis*.

When speaking, e.g., of enthusiasm you should use *infectious*.
*Infective* could be used as synonym of *infectious*, but the NOAD reports that usage is dated. There is a difference between the first meaning given for *infectious*, and the first meaning given for *infective*.

Comment: 'Infective' is only used in medical context.

Answer (score 0):

We can find in medical textbook and journals: "infective endocarditis" and "infectious endocarditis", as well, when talking about disease (mechanisms, process, cause, etiology). However, "infective" is more usual.

Examples:
• “Infective endocarditis” In: Goldman-Cecil Medicine, 2020 by Elsevier, 26th edition, section 8: Cardiovascular Disease, chapter 67
• “Infectious endocarditis” In: Textbook of Critical Care, 2017 by Elsevier, 7th edition, part 5: Cardiovascular, chapter 86
• “Infectious endocarditis” In: Textbook of Critical Care, 2017 by Elsevier, 7th edition, part 8: Infectious Diseases, chapter 128
• “Infective endocarditis” In: The New England Journal of Medicine [Clinical Practice], 2013, volume 368, pages 1425-1433